# function getHash()

Tags: javascript, jquery

У меня есть страничка, на которой есть меню, которое отвечает за содержание контента в окне, она реализована через:

```
function getHash() {
var hash = location.hash.replace(/^#/, '');
$('#hsh1').removeClass('w--tab-active');
$('#hshtab1').removeClass('w--current');

$('#hsh2').removeClass('w--tab-active');
$('#hshtab2').removeClass('w--current');

<!-- check hash -->
if (hash=="") {
$('#hsh1').addClass('w--tab-active');
$('#hshtab1').addClass('w--current');
};

if (hash=="tab1") {
$('#hsh1').addClass('w--tab-active');
$('#hshtab1').addClass('w--current');
};
```

Встал вопрос, как сделать прямую ссылку на нужную кнопку, по умолчанию при переходе на страницу отображается первая вкладка (активна первая кнопка меню), а нужна ссылка, чтоб при переходе по ней, отображалось содержание заданной кнопки меню. Спасибо заранее.

Собственно ссылка на страницу: http://ratium.ru/products.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для начала, вам нужно вызвать `getHash()` после того, как страница загрузилась:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        getHash();
    }
</script>
```

Далее в функции у вас идет получение хэша, отсекаются лишние символы и в зависимости от переменной уже добавляются активные классы. Попробуйте теперь перейдти по ссылке: http://ratium.ru/products.html#tab2

Comment: Спасибо друг!!!

Comment: @КаbbyU всегда пожалуйста, обращайтесь, И если ответ помог, засчитайте его как верный ;-)